# Is the notion of 'divergence to infinity in a direction' used?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, riemannian-geometry, divergence-operator, metric-geometry

In $\mathbb R$ a sequence can diverge to infinity in two directions: $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. These two cases of divergence are quite different from a sequence that diverges to "nowhere", like $\{(-1)^n\}$. One can be interested, for example, in the behavior of a function in one of these two directions of infinity.

Is there a similar notion for sequences in the complex plane? (Or other spaces) Does it arise naturally in some field of study? What are possible uses for it?

I imagine, for example, that the sequence $\{ni\}$ could be said to diverge to infinity in the direction $i$, whereas the sequence $\{ne^{in\sqrt2}\}$ could be said to diverge to infinity in "every direction", or in a "divergent direction", or in a "set of directions".

---

**Edit**: Added two geometry tags, following the comment of Moishe Cohen

Comment: The most common way to proceed in the complex plane is to consider absolute values and to just consider divergence to infinity with respect to absolute value. Yet it is possible to do what you propose. Right now I do not know a good reference or application though.

Comment: On the [Reimann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) there is only one infinity and all sequences which "diverge to infinity" (*as opposed to "diverging to nowhere"*) can be thought of on the sphere as instead *converging* to infinity instead using the Reimannian metric.

Comment: Sure, why not? To the divergent infinity in all directions, we'd probably shoot this down what WolframAlpha calls [complex infinity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexInfinity.html), and to the other, [directed infinity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectedInfinity.html).

Comment: @quid WolframAlpha has almost everything lol

Comment: Yes, this field of study is called geometry (metric geometry and Riemannian geometry to be more precise) and describing different ways to diverge to infinity (different directions of divergence), is quite important. Consider for instance:  [Gromov boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov_boundary).

Comment: @MoisheCohen first time I hear about that! Thank you

Comment: The real projective plane has a whole line of points at infinity. In this setting the lines $y=0$ and $y=1$ can be said to meet at a point at infinity, but a different point than the one the lines $x=0$ and $x=1$ meet at.

Comment: @MoisheCohen The OP probably wanted the idea of compactification of metric and topological spaces ? $\mathbb{C}$ can be compactified in many different ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this field of study is called geometry (metric geometry and Riemannian geometry to be more precise) and describing different ways to diverge to infinity (different directions of divergence), is quite important. Consider for instance: [Gromov boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov_boundary). In their book "Encyclopedia of Distances" (pp. 116-117), M.Deza and E.Deza list 5 different ideal boundaries (and some of these 5 items have several subitems), which all capture different aspects of diverging to infinity in different directions in different spaces. (Actually, there are more boundaries than they list, once one realizes that probabilists also have ways to capture divergence to infinity, resulting in, say, Poisson, Furstenberg and Martin boundaries.) As for the complex plane, one gets the circle as the ideal boundary (in item 1 on the Deza-Deza list). This corresponds to divergence to infinity along one of the rays starting at the origin. (Each ray gives one direction.) One can start at different points in the plane, then parallel rays yield the same direction of divergence.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was looking for :). Can you please elaborate a little on why these different aspects of divergence are important or what they are used for?

Comment: @dafinguzman: I will, but it takes a bit of time. It also depends on your background: Are you taking (already took) a complex analysis class? A topology class? A differential geometry class? (Or self-read, does not matter.)

Comment: I took a complex analysis class once, and I have a basic knowledge of topology in normed spaces